# Questions that look like they're probably best asked on the project's mailing list

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840229/kid-templates-discover-all-keywords), which asks about a Python templating library that has only [4 mentions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22kid+template%22). I get the feeling the question has a high chance of going unanswered, so I posted a comment suggesting the OP ask on the project's mailing list. After that though, I began to wonder whether it was the right thing.

Was my comment appropriate? Is there a better way to handle such questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your comment is helpful because you also state in the comment the reason why you think it might be better to ask on a mailing list.  The asker can make his/her own judgment whether he/she trusts your comment or not based on the reason you wrote.

In contrast, just writing “Ask on a mailing list” will not be so helpful (even if it is ultimately the right thing to do) because the asker will not have any clue whether he/she should trust the comment or not.