# How to handle "mailing list questions" when there is no mailing list

Tags: discussion, too-localized, external-project

When the SproutCore 2.0 project was renamed to Ember.js, it abandoned its old mailing list and started directing all questions to Stack Overflow.

In principle, this is not bad at all. It increases the popularity of Stack Overflow and keeps the active users of the framework from answering the same questions over and over again. It also clearly encourages a lot of new users to post very specific problems to Stack Overflow.

As an active SO user, I'm happy to help others with their questions, but since there is no mailing list at all, the [emberjs](/questions/tagged/emberjs) tag gets flooded with a lot of one-time questions and problems which do not really fit our Q&A format (e.g. [Requesting advice for "visually" filter a collection in ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674176/requesting-advice-for-visually-filter-a-collection-in-ember-js) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567428/rake-pipeline-cache-buster-and-a-minifier). It's annoying for existing users to have to flag, edit, comment on or vote to close these posts all the time when they just want to answer good questions.

What should we do when projects — not just Ember.js — rely on Stack Overflow as their only user support? How should "one-time questions" be handled?

Comment: I don't consider this a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77053/questions-that-look-like-theyre-probably-best-asked-on-the-projects-mailing-list since this project does not own a mailing list.

Comment: I've seen "just use SO for support" several times in the past few days. Whether or not it's a good idea, I don't think this particular genie is going back in its bottle. The example I remember at the moment is [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/): "To get help on a specific question or problem, use [so]. We monitor these questions using [this RSS feed](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=guava&sort=newest).)"

Comment: See also [Use Stack Overflow as the official support site of an open-source project](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19852/use-stack-overflow-as-the-official-support-site-of-an-open-source-project)

Answer (score 3):

We should handle questions for various technologies the same; regardless of whether the organization provides direct support, or refers users to SO.  Supporting a technology is not the SO community's job.

If the questions don't meet SO's guidelines for good questions (too localized, too vague, a rant or open discussion), then we should vote to close for appropriate reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it's a good idea for (fingers down throat) Facebook, I suppose we'll all survive emberjs.